# How can I randomly display imageview B2 at different position on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

now b2 is displaying at one position,i want it to print randomly on the screen.i used fade animation but it is actualy fadeing at one point i want the image view to run in randam position on the screen.

```
public class page2 extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView b2;
int count = 0;
Handler handler = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2);

    Intent c = getIntent();
    String name = c.getStringExtra("t");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    b2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redball);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(page2.this, R.anim.fade);
    b2.startAnimation(animation);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            count = count + 1;

        }
    });


    handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable t = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Page3.class);
            d.putExtra("count", count);
            d.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(d);


        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(t, 4000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RelativeLayout as container, then set LayoutParams to the ImageView. Set the position using b2.layout(startX, startY, endX, endY), then call invalidate()

Comment: I am a begginer,sorry to ask u.Can u please provide a sample code.